# How to solve: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: makefile, ld, android-source, linker-errors

I use AOSP to build Android.
I use these commands to build Android on my Ubuntu 17.04:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
repo sync -j8
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch
make -j8
```

and after 30 minutes this error came, anybody knows how to fix it?

```
host Executable: tblgen (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/tblgen)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you performed [all required steps](https://source.android.com/source/initializing) to establish build environment?

Comment: @Gluttton yes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these solutions will solve the problems:

## for `-lGL` error:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

## for `-lX11` error:

add this line `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lX11` to the file 
`development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/renderer/Android.mk`

## More information:

- http://developers-club.com/posts/209206/
- http://www.mamicode.com/info-detail-232796.html

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you have not completely followed the "Establishing a Build Environment" instructions completely.

I see you're trying to build Android Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.1) on Ubuntu 17 - please note that this is not a supported build / host environment and may not function correctly.

It would appear that you have a misconfigured or missing installs of the libx11-dev and libgl1-mesa-dev libraries (or whatever their Ubuntu 17 equivalents are named).

I would recommend installing Ubuntu 14 and trying Android L or N instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `libGL.so` file. This is the OpenGL library. Ensure that you have the appropriate OpenGL library installed and it is part of the search path (see `-L` directives).

Comment: when i use `make -j8` again, it shows same kind of error except instead of `-lGL` it shows `-lX11` how i can fix that?

Comment: You seem to have several libraries missing at once and they show up in random order based on your parallel build. X11 is the X Windowing library. I wouldn't expect it to be needed when building for Android, as Android is not using the X Windowing system. It is hard to tell what the underlying problem really is.

Comment: I use this command `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6  /usr/bin/libx11.so` and after that i get this error:
`/usr/bin/ld: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/emulator_renderer_intermediates/main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XInitThreads'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @shp, try build with `make showcommands` - sometimes it can give a hint.

Comment: @Gluttton `$ ~/make-3.81/make showcommands
make: *** No rule to make target `showcommands'.  Stop.`

Comment: @shp, `-b android-4.0.1_r1` - yep, it looks like old version of android.

Comment: @Gluttton yes it is not new because new versions are more than 20GB to download! this one is 12GB.